# "if... were to..." form can only be used with unlikely but "possible" conditions, not for "impossible" conditions?

Tags: past-tense, subjunctive-mood

I am confused over the difference using "were to" and past forms in conditionals.

Was told that "were to" is only for unlikely but "possible" conditions but past form is for impossible/fantastical.

For the following sentences, 1 is correct but 2 was deemed to be wrong.

1) If I had three heads, what kind of hat would I wear? - OK

2) If I were to have three heads, what kind of hat would I wear? - NOT OK

Hope to seek more advice and if u have any links/resources, please do provide them. Thanks :)

Comment: Indeed, (2) is wrong, but not for the reasons you were told. *If I were to* is generally a ***future*** construction (although this is very fuzzy, with many exceptions, and may depend on your dialect), so you wouldn't say *If I were to have three heads*, although you might say *If I were to grow a second head*.

Comment: To paraphrase the previous comment (I *personally* don't have any issue with *were to* in this context, but I acknowledge the point being made), the *were* sentence in the question could be changed to the following: *If I were **a person with three heads**, what kind of a hat would I wear?* That would alleviate any particular objection  (again, I don't have an objection to the original version myself), while retaining the use of *were* in a way acceptable to everyone.